# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' when using ionic build with--release tag

Tags: cordova

I'm using the ionic run command to generate an apk.
As soon as I put the **--release** tag, it throws two errors. It seems it's related to the resources.

**Cordova command**

```
ionic cordova build android --release --prod --verbose
```

**Errors**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows
Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile '..\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

and

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
```

I tried the following:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova resources -f
```

Additional informations:

My Gradle version is 5.4.1, it's added to PATH and Android Studio is configured to use this specific version.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, it looks like it comes from the splash.png file.

If the file is too big, it looks it won't work. (Anyone knows the maximum file size limit ?)

**Solution**: use a smaller splash.png image.

Comment: I tried to reduce the splash screen size. But after the build, the size of the splash screen increases automatically & build fails again. Did you face this issue?

Comment: @AnkushJain It might comes for the splash screen still beign too large