# Execution failed for task ‘:app:mergeReleaseResources’ when doing –release –prod build

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I am having a problem when trying to do a release build for my Android App so that I can upload it to the Play Store. When I run the following command: ionic cordova build --release --prod android I get the following error 'Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #7: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\projects...\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.'

From what I have been able to find on the web, this is due to the splash image being to large. *please see the following  -[Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' when using ionic build with--release tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450884/execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-when-using-ionic-build-wi)*

Has anybody encountered this issue before and how could I resolve it?

Ps, I don't have enough reputation to comment on the linked post, hence why I am asking a new question.

I have tried:
 - Adding and removing the Android platform
 - Regenerating the Resources (ionic cordova resources -f)
 - Compressing the Images

Full terminal output from failure on wards:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #7: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\projects...\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:96)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.RegisteredAaptService.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:61)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.workeractions.WorkerActionServiceRegistry$shutdownAllRegisteredServices$1$1.run(WorkerActionServiceRegistry.kt:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
32 actionable tasks: 30 executed, 2 up-to-date
C:\projects...\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: C:\projects...\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #7: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\projects...\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:96)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.RegisteredAaptService.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:61)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.workeractions.WorkerActionServiceRegistry$shutdownAllRegisteredServices$1$1.run(WorkerActionServiceRegistry.kt:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Ionic Info:

Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (C:\Users...Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.5.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 19 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:
   NodeJS : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10

Comment: For anyone else facing this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54615423 solved the issue for me :)